# URL do not change even after request dispatching in servlet

Tags: servlets, requestdispatcher

I am forwarding my request from Login servlet to a FacultyHomePage.jsp located in faculty folder(which is subfolder)....The page is displayed but url remains /LoginServlet.
Why isn't the url changing??

```
    HttpSession sc= request.getSession();
          if(usertype==0)
          {
              sc.setAttribute("type", usertype);
              sc.setAttribute("id",id );
         rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/faculty/FacultyHomePage.jsp");
         rd.forward(request, response);
          }
```

Comment: Because you did a **forward**

Comment: I am new to this concept.Please can you explain how to change the url?

Answer (score 5):

New `request` object will not be created in request dispatcher. Check [RequestDispatcher.forward](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) method.

If you want a URL change then use [`response.sendRedirect(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Yes thnx,that's working but now I am not getting the session created in my login servlet.Is this related to sendRedirect()???

Comment: You can get session forcefully with the statement `session = request.getSession(true);` Before that you can check if a session already got created using `if(session != null){session = request.getSession(true);}`.

Comment: @Vini did you mean that you are not getting session stored values